# Discord js TypeError: Cannot read property members

Tags: discord.js

Hello i have this code,

```
user = message.guild.members.fetch(id2).then((use,err)
```

And i have this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of null

Please can yuo help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`message.guild` is not initialized. You could check if it is null before use eg

```
if(message.guild){
    user = message.guild.members.fetch(id2).then((use,err) ...
}else{
   //do something when it is not initialized
}
```

Comment: i have this error **SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list** my code is here [LINK](https://codeshare.io/50EbMn)

Comment: You may included the remainder of your code instead of writing the "..." . The answer has been edited to remove the "!" in the if condition to test if message.guild has been initialized then execute the code that fetches the member with id2

Comment: The error is not about it being not initialized, but it's because received message was a direct message to the bot. in DMs there is no guild, so it's `null`. To avoid that, you should do that only when `message.channel.type` is something that is valid channel type for a guild.

Comment: @tipakA that sounds like the core of an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor What i meant was that while the answer is technically correct, it happens from different reason library wise, and should be handled differently.

Comment: @tipakA I'm not saying you are wrong, I'm saying it sounds like you have context/library specific knowledge of the situation, and a context specific answer would be more useful to the OP, than the general js answer provided. I'm trying to encourage you to write that useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your error occurs because the `message` object refers to a message that was received as a DM. Because of how DMs work, there is no `guild` or `member` property for such message (they are left as `null`s).

To avoid that, you should handle direct messages slightly differently. The easiest and most commonly used way is to completely stop direct messages from running your message event code. This can be done by adding

```js
if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
```

at the very top of your event.

As that makes it impossible to initiate commands in DMs, even if they don't need to be executed in a guild to work (like ping command for example), this might be not what you want. In such case, you should implement a way to determine if command someone tried to run in DM is "allowed" to be executed there. Implementations for that vary depending on command handling implementation, but snippet below is basic princinple.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ /g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'memberinfo') {
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return message.reply('this command cannot be run in DMs.');
    // Actual command code
  }
});
```